# Multiple ssh hop connections with Putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, putty

Best

Basically, I've the next line of code :

```
ssh -i AWS-EC2.pem -o ProxyCommand='ssh -i Server-Key abc@52.00.00.00 nc %h %p' AWS-User@99.00.00.00
```

But, what I would like to have, (And not able to do (yet)) is, to create a connection from my **windows 10** pc with the AWS-EC2 server *via* **PuTTY**.

In general, we have 1 **server** which you can only access with a key "**Server-Key**", and via this connection, we should be able to connect with the **AWS-EC2-server** via **AWS-EC2.pem**

Thus:

**my_pc ---** *Server-key* **--->  Server  ---** *AWS-EC2.pem* **---> AWS-EC2-server**

- I already made 2 ppk files frome the *Server-key* & *AWS-EC2.pem*

kind regards

Comment: @Martin Prikryl - It didn't work - a.k.a it isn't an exact duplicate + I found the solution

Comment: But it's just `-i key` switch for the Plink, the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem,

```
ssh -i AWS-EC2.pem -o ProxyCommand='ssh -i Server-Key abc@52.00.00.00 nc %h %p' AWS-User@99.00.00.00
```

whereby you've a two keys (AWS-EC2.pem and Server-key), 
You've to configure your PuTTY as follows. + don't forget to generate 2 pkk files from the PuTTY generator

[image]

[image]

[image]